# Angular. CLI Cannot read property 'split'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I try to deploy my beginner Angular 4 CLI app to GitHub pages. I have routes that work on my computer and don't work on GitHub Pages.
When I try to follow link that should show one of two more components nothing works and console contains a huge error.

Here's my site https://gultyaev.github.io/modxvm/

You can try to follow any of two links that aren't selected. And then check console.

Here's my repo https://github.com/gultyaev/modxvm

Also, as I see, it happens only in production. E.g. I do `ng serve --prod` it doesn't work(routes). If I start just `ng serve` everything works.

I think that it's because of minimizing. But I have no idea what's exactly minimizes wrong.

Comment: is there any API call you are making with Tokens

Comment: I really don't know what's causing this issue... and I don't know if it will help, but I went to the source and the error is being thrown in [**this line**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5293794316cc1b0f57d5d88b3fefdf6ae29d0d97/packages/router/src/shared.ts#L114).

Comment: It's very strange, because I saw one site built on Angular 2 CLI, with similar routes' settings and this worked. I did'n find anything that can help. Also I cannot check this at my computer, because it works without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed this issue in this way:

```
ng update --verbose=true

  Name                               Version                  Command to update
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @angular/cdk                       7.0.0 -> 7.3.2           ng update @angular/cdk
  @angular/cli                       7.0.1 -> 7.3.2           ng update @angular/cli
  @angular/core                      7.0.0 -> 7.2.5           ng update @angular/core
  @angular/material                  7.0.0 -> 7.3.2           ng update @angular/material
  @ngrx/store                        6.1.0 -> 7.2.0           ng update @ngrx/store
```

And then update one module after another like:

```
ng update @angular/core
```

Some of this ng update requires --force flag

```
ng update @angular/core --force
```

this allows me to update all modules without this error.